# Why IONIC creating android-armv7-debug.apk and android-x86-debug.apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, apk

I am creating IONIC 2 App and it was working good and my ionic build android command was creating **android-debug.apk** for testing but recently I am not sure what change affected and it is creating **android-armv7-debug.apk** and **android-x86-debug.apk** files which are higher in size almost 50MB and also tried --release parameter it is creating same unsigned files.

Question:-

1) What changes might have affected this?
2) How can I build **android-debug.apk** and **android-release-unsigned.apk** as what it generally builds?

Thanks Sanny

Comment: which CLI command have you used?

Comment: ionic build android

Comment: are you using cross walk in your project?

Comment: I am not sure what is cross walk...I am new to IONIC

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the command which you have used, use below one and see that.

**Note:** This is the path: `..\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk` where it will be generated.Before running the below command remove old apk's.

```
ionic run android --device
```

Or you can run on Emulator

```
ionic emulate android
```

Comment: ionic run android --device do not work in my system as USB ports are disabled.

Comment: Can't you enable it? Is that due to company rule or something like that?

Comment: Yes that's why I need to create apk and uploading it to test fairy to test in real device.

Comment: OK. can't you do that on emulator?

Answer (score 0):

When you add [Crosswalk](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1029764/building-combined-armv-x-apk-after-crosswalk-integ) plugin to Ionic/Cordova project, then two separate builds are created. One for armv7 and other for x86.

- [Building Combined armv7 / x86 apk After Crosswalk Integration in an
  Cordova / Ionic Project](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1029764/building-combined-armv-x-apk-after-crosswalk-integ)
- [Crosswalk Frequently-asked questions](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html)